# How to make gitflow allow multiple hotfix creation?

Tags: macos, git-flow, hotfix

I'm struggling to set gitflow to allow multiple hotfixes creation...
I've run the commands:

```
git config --add gitflow.multi-hotfix true
git config --global gitflow.multi-hotfix true
```

And when I run:

```
git config --list
git config --global --list
```

I can see that it is set properly

```
gitflow.multi-hotfix=true
```

But still... every time I try to create a new hotfix it asks me to first finish the current hotfix...

My mac book pro is running Mojave 10.14.1 (18B75)

Another detail that may help, I've noticed that every-time I run the adding command another line in the configuration is added with the exact same info gitflow.multi-hotfix=true. So, I've tried clearing all settings and start from scratch and run the following:

```
git config --unset gitflow.multi-hotfix
git config --unset-all gitflow.multi-hotfix
```

But no matter how many times I try and run these commands the line of allowing multiple hotfixes remains, but I cannot actually create multiple hotfix branches..

Comment: Someone sent me the solution in private and it worked!
`brew install git-flow-avh --HEAD`
`git config gitflow.multi-hotfix true`
`git config --get gitflow.multi-hotfix (verify that it returns true)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone sent me the solution in private and it worked!

```
brew install git-flow-avh --HEAD 

git config gitflow.multi-hotfix true git config --get gitflow.multi-hotfix
```

verify that the last call returns true